Is the statement correct with respect to the circuit depicted in the ER diagram?

An employee can work in multiple offices.
Please evaluate this expression as applied to this ER diagram. It seems wrong to me.
The relationship between Office and Company is one-to-many. This implies that many companies have many employees working in one office. Accordingly, many employees work in many companies, but these companies are in one office. Accordingly, workers can work in different companies but in one office. For the original formulation to be correct, the relationship between Office and Company must be many-to-many. Am I correct? Please write if I am wrong and point out the error in my reasoning.

Yes, seems wrong semantically based on the assumption of what an "Office" is.


The relationship between Office and Company is one-to-many.

Yes. So there might be Companies A, B, C all in the New York Office.

This implies that many companies have many employees working in one office.

That might be true, but not necessarily. (That is, not "implied".) Companies A, B, C each have 20 Employees; all 60 are in New York Office. But Company D's Office is in Chicago; that has one Employee; there's no other Company in Chicago. (Many-to-many doesn't exclude Many-to-One nor exclude One-to-many; nor exclude One-to-one.)

workers can work in different companies ...

Yes. For example, in both Company A and B (both in NY as it happens).

...  but in one office.

Not necessarily. Company D needs a new Employee but only Part-time. An Employee for Company C in NY likes to go fishing (but also likes to go to shows on Broadway). They take up the Part-time position for Company D in Chicago; and switch to Part-time for their continuing job at Company C in NY. Commuting is the Employee's problem.
The given ER diagram still accurately represents the situation.

An employee can work in multiple offices.

QED.
